# Magento 2 di:compile error - Directory not empty

Tags: magento2.3.4, setup-di-compile

How to solve the following error, The directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(C:/xampp/htdocs/mage/generated/code/Magento/Framework): Directory not empty

Comment: rm -rf generated/* from C:/xampp/htdocs/mage directory

Comment: "r m" is not recognized as an internal or external command @sohel rana

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this things :

1. Commented this `"generated"` folder from magento root.
2. Now run the following commands from CLI.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```